# JQUERY to update the font family for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I am using a font family that does not render special characters characters such as &,£ etc. so im looking for a solution to target all special characters (site wide) and change them to a different (similar) font family.

Can this be achieved using JQUERY? For example declare an string array that holds the characters i want to target and write some code to update these?

Using the following JQUERY it will target the word package in any h3’s site wide, apply the span class font-fix and update the word to say test

```
$('h3').each(function () {    
    $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(‘package’, '<span class=\'font-fix\'>test</span>')
    );
});
```

However when I attempt to target the £ sign or any other special char it doesn’t seem to work.

```
$('h3').each(function () {    
    $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(‘£’, '<span class=\'font-fix\'>£</span>')
    );
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong please? – Id like to be able to target all heading tags and paragraph tags replacing the special characters

*edit

I have the following css but the fall back fonts are never used when characters are not rendered.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{font-family:"know-your-product-webfont", "Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;}
```

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: Usually you would do that in CSS. When you set `font-family: "My Weird Font", "Arial", sans-serif;` then when the first font doesn't include a character, then the next font will be used to render it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response i am using the following css but it does fallback to another font-family h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{font-family:"know-your-product-webfont", "Roboto Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;}